# error al mostrar datos en programa c

Tags: c

Estoy tratando me mostrar "edad media","menores de edad","jubilados(60 años)","edad mayor" y "edad menor.

pero el programa somo le muestra la edad media y los demas los deja en blanco, podrian ayudarme a solucionar este problema porfavor.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main() {
    int edad, totalmenores=0, totaljubilados=0, edadmenor, edadmayor=0, suma = 0, c = 0;
    float media;
 
    printf("\nIngrese la edad de la persona: ");
    scanf("%d",&edad);
    edadmenor = edad;
 
    while (edad > 0) {
      suma = suma + edad;
      c ++;
      if (edad<=17)
        totalmenores=totalmenores+1;
      if (edad>=60)
        totaljubilados=totaljubilados+1;
 
      if (edad > edadmayor)
        edadmayor = edad;
      if (edad <edadmenor)
        edadmenor = edad;
      printf("\nIngrese la edad de la persona: ");
      scanf("%d",&edad);
    }
 
    media = suma / c;
 
    printf("\nProemdio de edades: %.1f" , media);
    printf("\nEdad mayor: %.1f" ,edadmayor);
    printf("\nEdad menor: %.1f" ,edadmenor);
    printf("\nTotal de jubilados: %.1f" ,totaljubilados);
    printf("\nTotal de menores de edad: %.1f" ,totalmenores);
 
  return 0;
}
```

[image: muestra del error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El programa no muestra un número válido para esas variables porque son de tipo `int` y en `printf` el formato es del tipo incorrecto (`float`).

Puedes cambiar el formato a entero (`%d`) o el tipo de las variables a `float`:

```
printf("\nEdad mayor: %d", edadmayor);
printf("\nEdad menor: %d", edadmenor);
printf("\nTotal de jubilados: %d" , totaljubilados);
printf("\nTotal de menores de edad: %d", totalmenores);
```

Por cierto, `media = suma / c` es una división de enteros porque ambos operandos son enteros. Para no perder los decimales necesitas que al menos uno de los dos sea de tipo `float`. Por ejemplo:

```
media = (float)suma / c;
```

---

Mencionar también que `suma += edad` es equivalente a `suma = suma + edad` y más conciso.

De manera similar, puedes usar `totalmenores++` en lugar de `totalmenores=totalmenores+1`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me salvaste